# Proof of the existence of an optimal MDP with a stochastic reward signal?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm following [Sutton's](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~straka/courses/npfl114/2016/sutton-bookdraft2016sep.pdf) book on Reinforcement Learning, and he casually states that "There is always at least one policy that is better than
or equal to all other policies" for a given finite MDP. This is trivially the case for deterministic policies, since there is a finite number of policies. Is there any proof when one allows for stochastic policies? Or any proof that a stochastic policy can always be improved by a deterministic one?

The value function is bounded and real-valued and therefore there is a least upper bound, but how can we know it is achieved by a valid policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I will try to answer anyway: It depends.

If the search space only allows policies that have at least one state for which a non-deterministic action selection takes place, then no; trivially there is no (fully) deterministic policy that is better then the optimal stochastic policy.

If you allow all stochastic policies in the sense that $\pi(a|s)\neq 0$ for any number ($\geq 1$) of $a$ available in $s$ and further $\forall a,s~:\pi(a|s)\in [0,1] $ (there is no restriction on the probability value for a state-action pair) then yes, deterministic policies are at least equally good.

**Proof:**

Let $\pi^*$ be an optimal, non-deterministic policy. This means that  $\exists \hat{s}~ \exists a : \pi^*(a|\hat{s}) \in (0,1)$, where $\pi^*(\cdot|s)$ is the probability distribution function for the optimal policy $\pi^*$ in state $s$.

We can find a value function $V^*$ as well as a Q-function $Q^*$ that correspond to $\pi^*$ and a relationship between them
\begin{equation}
V^*(s) = \sum_{i=0}^N\pi^*(a_i|s)Q^*(s,a_i)
\end{equation}

W.l.o.g. $Q^*(s,a_1)\geq Q^*(s,a_2)\geq\dots\geq Q^*(s,a_N)$. Choosing $\alpha_i \in [0,1]$, we can now construct a family of policies $\pi^{\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_N}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\pi^{\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_N}(a|s) = 
\begin{cases}
\pi^*(a|s) +\sum_{i=2}^N \alpha_i&,~\textrm{if}~a=a_1~\textrm{and}~ s = \hat{s}\\
\pi^*(a|s) - \alpha_i&,~\textrm{if}~a=a_i~\textrm{and}~ s = \hat{s}~\textrm{for}~i\geq 2\\
\pi^*(a|s)&,~\textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}

Choose $\alpha_N = \pi^*(a_N|\hat{s})~,~\alpha_i = 0$ otherwise; we can compare

\begin{align}
V^*(s) &= \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\pi^*(a_i|s)Q^*(s,a_i) + \pi^*(a_N|s)Q^*(s,a_N)\\
&\leq \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\pi^*(a_i|s)Q^*(s,a_i) + \pi^*(a_N|s)Q^*(s,a_1) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\pi^*(a_i|s)Q^*(s,a_i) + \alpha_N Q^*(s,a_1) \\
&= V^{0,\dots,0,\pi^*(a_N|s)}(s)
\end{align}
(Note: for [my] convenience I've written s instead of $\hat{s}$ here.)

Analogous for $\alpha_i=\pi^*(a_i|s)$ and we arrive at
\begin{equation}
V^*(s) \leq V^{\pi^*(a_2|\hat{s}),\dots,\pi^*(a_n|\hat{s})}~\forall s
\end{equation}
meaning that the policy $\pi^{\pi^*(a_2|\hat{s}),\dots,\pi^*(a_n|\hat{s})}$ which is deterministic in $\hat{s}$ is at least as good as $\pi^*$.

Doing this for each stochastic state in $\pi^*$ constructs a new policy which is at least as good as the previous optimal policy, but deterministic.

---

A shorter, but I think less insightful, proof following the same line of thought (sketch):

W.l.o.g. $Q^*(s,a_1)\geq Q^*(s,a_2)\geq\dots\geq Q^*(s,a_N)$.

\begin{equation}
V^*(s) = \sum_{i=0}^N\pi^*(a_i|s)Q^*(s,a_i) \leq \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^N\pi^*(a_i|s)}_{=1}Q^*(s,a_1) = Q^*(s,a_1)
\end{equation}

Choosing
\begin{equation}
\pi(a|s) = 
\begin{cases}
1&,~\textrm{if}~a = a_1\\
0&,~\textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
follows that $V^*(s)\leq V^\pi(s)~\forall s$. $\pi$ is deterministic by construction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. Let $Q^*$ be the optimal Q-function. (Note that $Q^*(s,a)$ can be defined without explicit reference to an optimal policy as the supremum of the expected utility-to-go starting from state $s$, the supremum being taken over all policies starting with action $a$.) Then a stochastic policy $\pi$ is optimal iff $\pi(s)$ maximizes $Q^*(s,\cdot)$ almost surely for each state $s$. So clearly a deterministic policy always exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think that both answers are kinda flawed and I even think that the remark in the question itself

> This is trivially the case for deterministic policies, since there is a finite number of policies

is not trivially true (maybe I'm too dumb to see it but I think that there is an important piece missing, see below).

Given a Markov Decision Process consisting of random variables $(S_t, R_t, A_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}_0}$, put

$$ G_t := \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}_0} \gamma^k R_{t+k}$$

for any state $s$ let $v^\pi(s) = E^\pi[G_t|S_t=s]$ for any $t$ arbitrary. It is already not clear that this variable $G_t$ converges in any sense but if we assume that there are only finitely many $L^1$ rewards involved or all rewards are bounded then this converges and $E^\pi[G_t|S_t=s]$ is independent of the point in time $t$ (given that all policies we consider are stationary).

What "you people" always claim is the following: consider a fixed policy $\pi$ and a fixed state $s$. Assuming that I change that policy to $\pi'$ but only on all other states $s' \neq s$ is it true that $v^\pi(s) = v^{\pi'}(s)$? **I do not think so (at least I cannot easily find a proof for that).** Changing the behaviour only on one single state $s$ can change all values of $v^\pi$! The property you are looking for is not true for 'the function $\pi \mapsto v^\pi$' but rather for the following construction:

We know that under suitable conditions, the so-called Bellman equation holds:

$$v^\pi(s) = E^\pi[R_t|S_t=s] + \gamma \int_{s'} p(s'|s) v^\pi(s') ds'$$

see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243384/deriving-bellmans-equation-in-reinforcement-learning for a proof.

Consider the space $V$ of all bounded functions from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$. On this space we can define the operator
  $$v \mapsto ((L_\pi v)(s))_{s \in S}$$
where
  $$(L_\pi v)(s) = E[R_t|S_t=s] + \gamma \int_{s'} p(s'|s) v(s') ds'$$
(actually, the first term $E[R_t|S_t=s]$ does not depend on $\pi$ but the latter one $p(s'|s)$ does!) The Bellman equation is the motivation for that operator: $v^\pi$ is its unique fixed point.

Now given any $v \in V$ fixed and a policy $\pi$ and I change $\pi$ to $\pi'$ on all states $s' \neq s$ then
  $$(L_\pi v)(s) = (L_{\pi'} v)(s) ~~~~ (*)$$
i.e. the property you were looking for only holds for '$\pi \mapsto (L_\pi v)$' for a fixed $v$ but not for '$\pi \mapsto v^\pi$'!

The only proof I was really able to understand can be found in Puterman, Markov Decision Processes. He essentially proves in Chapter 6 that optimizing $L_\pi$ on $v^*$ is sufficient for obtaining on optimal policy.

Side note: one can understand it up to the facts that $E[G_t|S_t=\cdot]$ is actually not a function but a $P_{S_t}$-almost everywhere class of functions and up to the fact that $E[G_t|S_t=s]$ cannot be defined if $P[S_t=s]=0$, i.e. the vectors $v^\pi$ are 'incomplete'. The first thing can be fixed by restricting to the case where $S$ is discrete (then it actually becomes a function) and the second one can be fixed by not considering the single MDP as it but the MArkov Decision Automata that gives rise (in the sense of [Markov processes: Construction of the state variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292942/markov-processes-construction-of-the-state-variables)) to the MDP, i.e. we do not say 'given an MDP, $\pi(a|s) = p(a_t|s_t)$ is its policy' but we start by saying 'given a function $\pi : A \times S \to [0,1]$ such that for each $s$, $\int_a \pi(a|s) = 1$ we define canonical expressions for $v^\pi(s)$ even if, for example, $P[S_0=s]=0$' and we can do this because we actually *know* the value for $\pi(a|s_0)$ even if $P[S_0=s_0]=0$! Just wanted to note that because it was something that confused me for quite some time...